# Apply a mask to multiple lines (syntactic sugar?)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for an elegant (or more elegant) way to code a particular use case in numpy.  The use case is a large data set (so efficiency matters) with 100+ fields, over 1,000 lines of code, and multiple sections of code where I would like to process only a subset of the fields.  As long as I'm processing all observations, this is clean and efficient in plain numpy:

```
wages = np.arange(40000,60000,2000)
cg    = np.arange(0,100000,10000)
ded   = np.repeat([6000,9000],5) 
exem  = np.repeat([2000,4000],5) 

agi  = wages + cg
tinc = agi - ded
tinc = tinc - exem
```

But in many code subsections I want to process only a subset of the observations for, say, 30 lines of code and this is the best I can come up with:

```
agi  = wages + cg
mask = wages < 50001
tinc = agi

tinc[mask] = agi[mask] - ded[mask]
tinc[mask] = tinc[mask] - exem[mask]
```

That's not horrible, don't get me wrong, but multiply this by 100s of variables and hundreds of lines of code.  Is there any way to do something like the following, without resorting to cython/numba loops?

```
# fake code, just to convey the desired syntax
agi  = wages + cg
tinc = agi

mask( wages < 50001 ):    # i.e. inside a python loop, would be "if wages < 50001:"
   tinc = agi - ded
   tinc = tinc - exem
```

In other words, I'd like to define subsections of code and specify that the exact same mask should apply to every single array within the code section, without explicitly typing the mask for every singly array.

(Btw, I know there may be some alternative approaches via pandas, but for now would prefer to explore my best option via numpy.  I may re-ask this question with a pandas tag later on.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not recommending this, but… you *could* do it with a horribly magic context manager. For example:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def masking(namespace, mask):
    # If you don't have a fixed set of maskable variables, make it
    # an instance/global/local variables, like `_names`, or just
    # [name for name, value in namespace.items() if isiinstance(value, np.ndarray)]
    names = 'tinc agi dec exem'.split()
    stash = {name: namespace[name] for name in names}
    for name in names:
        namespace[name] = namespace[name][mask]
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        for name in names:
            namespace[name] = stash[name]
```

Now you can do this:

```
with masking(globals(), wages < 50001):
    tinc = agi - dec
    tinc = tinc - exem

with masking(self.__dict__, self.wages < 50001):
    self.tinc = self.agi - self.dec
    self.tinc = self.tinc - self.exem

# etc.
```

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to think about whether I'd want to do this or not!  But may be the only in numpy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about doing this *may* be to use [Numpy's masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html).

Numpy's documentation goes into further details, and I would recommend looking through it before starting. It will likely add some more complexity (you may or may not need to use [function under `numpy.ma`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html)), and you'll have to be careful that all of the operations in your code are still correct, but if you use masked arrays you could easily define a context manager like this:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def mask(clause, masked_arrays):
    for ma in masked_arrays:
        ma[~clause] = np.ma.masked
    yield
    for ma in masked_arrays:
        ma.mask = np.ma.nomask
```

Note that because the masking operations have to be in-place, it requires that the arrays you work with are masked arrays to begin with. And then you could easily use it like:

```
# Wrap arrays as masked arrays
mwages = np.ma.array(wages)
mcg = np.ma.array(cg)
... etc ...

with mask(mwages < 50001, [mwages, mcg, mded, ...]):
    # np.ma.compressed returns 1D array of non-masked items
    unmasked_tinc = np.ma.compressed(magi - mded - mexem)

    # or must change the masked one directly
```