# Most effective way to compute the pairwise minimum between a numpy array and a csr_matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have an numpy array `V` with a shape of `(1, 1000)`. I also have a csr_matrix `M` with a shape of `(100000, 1000)`. For every row `m` in `M`, I want to compute the pairwise minimum between `V` and `m`, and store all the results in a new matrix, and I want to do it efficiently. The final result should also be a matrix with a shape of `(100000, 1000)`.

Some approaches that I considered/tried:

- Iterate over each row of `M` with a for loop. This works, but it is quite slow.
- Convert `M` to a matrix: `numpy.minimum(V, M.toarray())` which takes a huge amount of memory.
- `numpy.minimum(V, M)` does not work. I get an error which says: `Comparing a sparse matrix with a scalar less than zero using >= is inefficient`.

What would be a good and efficient way to do this without taking too much memory or time?

Comment: Are some values of `v` negative?

Comment: I second @hpaulj's question.  If the values in `v` are nonnegative, there are some  reasonably efficient methods for this.

Comment: No, all the numbers in both `V` and `M` are between 0 and 1, inclusive.

Comment: This is a efficient solution for finding the element-wise maximum. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64920528/4045774

Answer (score 2):

If the values in `v` are nonnegative, this is a concise method that should be much faster than looping over each row:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

def rowmin(M, v):
    # M must be a csr_matrix, and v must be a 1-d numpy array with
    # length M.shape[1].  The values in v must be nonnegative.
    if np.any(v < 0):
        raise ValueError('v must not contain negative values.')

    # B is a CSR matrix with the same sparsity pattern as M, but its
    # data values are from v:
    B = csr_matrix((v[M.indices], M.indices, M.indptr))
    return M.minimum(B)
```

To allow negative values in `v`, this modification works, but a warning is generated when `v` has negative values, because the sparsity pattern in `B` has to be changed when the negative values are copied into it. (The warning could be silenced with a couple more lines of code.)  Many negative values in `v` will probably degrade the performance significantly.

```
def rowmin(M, v):
    # M must be a csr_matrix, and v must be a 1-d numpy array with
    # length M.shape[1].

    # B is a CSR matrix with the same sparsity pattern as M, but its
    # data values are from v:
    B = csr_matrix((v[M.indices], M.indices, M.indptr))

    # If there are negative values in v, include them in B.
    negmask = v < 0
    if np.any(negmask):
        negindices = negmask.nonzero()[0]
        B[:, negindices] = v[negindices]

    return M.minimum(B)
```

Comment: Beautiful solution. It worked like a charm and it is so damn fast. Thank you so much.  :)