# Why is a simple in-place addition much faster with numba than numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

According to the snippet below, performing an in-place addition with a numba jit-compiled function is ~10 times faster than with numpy's ufunc.

This would be understandable with a function performing multiple numpy operations as explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950943/why-is-numba-faster-than-numpy-here).

But here the improvement concern 1 simple numpy ufunc...
So why is numba so much faster ? I'm (naively ?) expecting that the numpy ufunc somehow internally uses some compiled code and that a task as simple as an addition would already be close to optimally optimized ?

More generally : should I  expect such dramatic performance differences for other numpy functions ? Is there a way to predict when it's  worth to re-write a function and numba-jit it ?

the code :

```py
import numpy as np
import timeit
import numba

N = 200
target1 = np.ones( N )
target2 = np.ones( N )

# we're going to add these values :
addedValues = np.random.uniform( size=1000000  )
# into these positions : 
indices = np.random.randint(N,size=1000000) 


@numba.njit
def addat(target, index, tobeadded):
    for i in range( index.size):        
        target[index[i]] += tobeadded[i]

# pre-run to jit compile the function
addat( target2, indices, addedValues)
target2 = np.ones( N ) # reset

npaddat = np.add.at
t1 = timeit.timeit( "npaddat( target1, indices, addedValues)", number=3, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit.timeit( "addat( target2, indices, addedValues)", number=3,globals=globals())
assert( (target1==target2).all() )

print("np.add.at time=",t1, )
print("jit-ed addat time =",t2 )
```

on my computer I get :

```
np.add.at time= 0.21222890191711485
jit-ed addat time = 0.003389443038031459
```

so more than a factor 10 improvement...

Comment: Without reading the `add.at` code we can't say.  I have observed that it is slower than the equivalent  `+=` (no duplicates). Maybe it's more general, handling more checks and dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ufunc.add.at()` is much more generic then your `addat()`. It iterates over the array elements and calls some unit operation function for each element. Let the unit operation function be `add_vectors()`. It adds two input vectors, where a vector means array elements in C-contiguous order and aligned. It utilizes SIMD operations if possible.

Because the `ufunc.add.at()` accesses elements randomly(not sequentially), the `add_vectors()` should be called multiple times for each pair of input elements. But your `addat()` does not have this penalty because Numba generates a machine code that accesses Numpy array elements directly.

You can see the overhead in the Numpy source at [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.23.5/numpy/core/src/umath/ufunc_object.c#L6171) and [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.23.5/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_arithm_fp.dispatch.c.src#L519) for example.

For your second question on the performance of other Numpy functions, I recommend to experiment by yourself, because both Numpy and Numba do so complex operations behind the scene.(My naive opinion is that a well written Numba implementation for a ufunc operation will perform better than the Numpy implementation, because Numba also utilizes SIMD operations if possible.)